# Adding a clickable area to the end of input box

Tags: html, css

Here is the code I am working from:

http://jsfiddle.net/5yEGX/

I wanted to put something at the end of this textbox, for example, two letters and an image to the end of the field like "UK " and this whole extra area is clickable as a link.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: The correct way is not to put that additional stuff into the text input field. Make container div with border. In this container div you place a textbox without border and next to it you position your additional stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @SvenBieder mentioned in his comment, you could accomplish this by putting the input field and anchor inside of a wrapper element and position/style them accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/5yEGX/5/

Comment: That is perfect, I was trying to hack one up myself to show you. What is the solution to the focus being on the inner textbox and not instead about the surrounding box?

Comment: I.e when you are on chrome, the inner text box now glows orange whereas the outer board used to glow. Is this achieved with javascript?

Comment: @user1738522 No.  The field highlighting is all Chrome.  I've never attempted to override the field highlighting in Chrome but I'm sure it is possible.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Joe's solution is best approach, but just for completeness I offer another solution using an absolute positioned div over the text area, it uses a bit of jquery to gather the text area width and position the overlay accordingly, see the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5yEGX/19/) .

**UPDATE:**
Updated the demo with a padding-right so the text don't reach the absolute positioned elements (UK+image).

Regards,

Comment: The issue here is that the text within the textbox runs underneath the absolutely positioned elements.  Could dynamically widen the container, I suppose.  ;)

Comment: @Joe yes, or set a padding-right on the input text so the text don't reach the the absolutely positioned elements. I've updated my answer with that example.